# Python module to take a video from webcam without using OpenCV

Tags: python

I want to video stream from my laptop to Raspberry Pi. Regarding that I need to access my laptop camera or my webcam which is connected to my laptop. I'm looking for a Python module to do this without using OpenCV. Does such module exist?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), [code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc. I guess you meant to ask for a Python module, right?

Comment: VLC (cvlc) should get the job done. You're not saying why you need a Python module.